# How to run python scripts in Atom with atom-python-run package?

Tags: python, atom-editor

I want to run a python script within Atom text editor on OSX.

I have installed the package `atom-python-run` to do that.

However in `Packages` menù I cannot find the package and right clicking on the file name I cannot find any useful option.

In the [official page](https://atom.io/packages/atom-python-run) there is written to press F5 or F6 to run the script but doing that tries to compile the script with the `gpp` package (which I had installed before) as if it were C/C++ code.

NOTE: An alternative is given by the `scripts` package which runs/compiles scripts according to the file name but I would like to use `atom-python-run`.

Comment: I'm getting some strange behavior with atom-python-run as well. The package is loaded and is designated under packages as python-runner. But selecting that never works. Clicking on F5 does work most of the time but not always.  I have the script module loaded as well. That seems to work all the time with cmnd-I key combo.  If I open a script and f5 doesn't work, I use cmnd-I and after doing that, f5 appears to work ok.  I'm still trying to determine why f5 doesn't always work.

Comment: After working with Atom for about an hour, playing with F5 and Script, I quit and closed Atom still unsure why F5 didn't always work.  I was doing something else which required me to open a terminal window. When I did this, the window went crazy opening tabs and plot windows all related to my Atom testing. There must have been 50 or more tabs and plots. I closed them all down and reopened Terminal to ensure I got them all. After doing that I reopened Atom and F5 and F6 worked fine.  So try opening a terminal window to be sure you don't have a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to find the package by going Settings -> Packages -> (search) `atom python run`

As for keybindings, use the keybinding resolver (`cmd-.`) to see what is happening. It sounds like there is a conflict, which can be resolved by disabling the `gpp-compiler` package keybindings, or specifying it yourself in the `keymap.cson` file.

I tried running a python script with `atom-python-run` just now, and it did make a terminal window appear. The window was hidden by default though. The package also can't handle file paths with spaces in them, so be mindful of that.